# In SQL how do I select based on a timestamp only if another criterion exists

Tags: sql, select, filter, timestamp

I don't even know how to ask this question. I have a table with names addresses type of address and a timestamp on when the address was added. Each person may have multiple addresses of each type.

```
Name   Addr  Type   Timestamp
a      abc   home   Jan 5 2022
a      def   home   Jul 5 2021
a      ghi   mail   Mar 3 2022
```

For example in the above scenario, I want to select the newest home address if it is available. If not, I want to select the newest mailing address. There are other address types too and I like work and alternate mailing address. I have an order of preference of the address type. And from that I want the newest address. In the table above I would want the first row even though the mailing address is newer.

I don't even know how to approach this problem so I don't know what to try. I would truly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please tag your question with which RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your RDBMS supports analystic window functions you would use a typical *row_number* solution:

```
with address as (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by Name order by Type, Timestamp desc) rnk
)
select *
from address
where rnk = 1;
```

If the desired ordering of *type* is not alphabetic you can introduce your own ordering using a case expression, eg

```
order by case Type when 'home' then 1 when 'email' then 2... end
```

Even better, normalise the table such that the type is stored separately and use its foreign key for ordering, ensuring the list of types are assigned a key in priority order.